# Como poner una barra scroll dentro de una tabla en html

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3

Buen día, quisiera saber si podían ayudarme con este problema, tengo un código en `javaScript` con el cual, al darle unos `inputs`, me genera una tabla de cuotas.

El problema es que a veces, los plazos son en años y la forma de pago es semanal, y se generaran muchas cuotas, y la pagina al cargar se hace muy larga. Quisiera saber si se puede hacer que esa tabla tenga un largo máximo y se le pueda poner una barra scroll para ir bajando dentro de esa tabla y ver todas las cuotas. Estoy usando `bootstrap` para el código `html`.

Aquí les pongo los códigos.

La parte de la tabla, está en la función de generar tabla de `javascript` al final. Gracias.

```js
function cargardiaDepago(valor) {
 if (valor == 1) {
  document.querySelector('#input_dia_pago').innerHTML = cargarSelectSemanas();
 } else if (valor == 2) {
 } else if (valor == 3) {
  document.querySelector('#input_dia_pago').innerHTML = cargarSelectDiasMes();
 } else if (valor == 4) {
  document.querySelector('#input_dia_pago').innerHTML = cargarSelectDiasMes();
 } else if (valor == 5) {
  document.querySelector('#input_dia_pago').innerHTML = cargarSelectDiasMes();
 }
}
function cargarSelectSemanas() {
 var select_dia_pago =
  "<label for='diapago'>Elija un dia de pago</label><select name='diapago' id='diapago' class='form-control' required><option value='0'>Elige un día de pago</option><option value='1'>Lunes</option><option value='2'>Martes</option><option value='3'>Miércoles</option><option value='4'>Jueves</option><option value='5'>Viernes</option></select> ";
 return select_dia_pago;
}
function cargarSelectDiasMes() {
 var select_dia_mes =
  "<label for='diapago'>Elija un dia del mes para pagar</label><input class='form-control' type='number' name='diapago' id='diapago' placeholder='Escribe un día del mes' value='1' min='1' max='31' step='1'required> ";
 return select_dia_mes;
}
const mes_especial = [];
const vector_mensual = [];
function guardar_mes_especial() {
 var inputmes = document.getElementById('mesEspecial');
 var ms = inputmes.options[inputmes.selectedIndex].text;
 var vs = document.getElementById('vectorMensual').value;
 if (ms != 'Elige un mes' && vs != 1) {
  mes_especial.push(ms);
  vector_mensual.push(vs);
 }
 document.querySelector('#mesespecial').innerHTML = generarTablaMesesEspeciales(mes_especial, vector_mensual);
 document.ready = document.getElementById('mesEspecial').value = '13';
 document.ready = document.getElementById('vectorMensual').value = '1';
}
function generarTablaMesesEspeciales(mes_especial, vector_mensual) {
 var tabla1 =
  "<table id='tablita1' class='table'> <thead class='thead-light'> <tr><th scope='col'>Mes</th><th scope='col'>Vector mensual</th></tr></thead>";
 tabla1 += '<tbody>';
 for (var i = 0; i < mes_especial.length; i++) {
  tabla1 += '<tr><td>' + mes_especial[i] + '</td><td>' + vector_mensual[i] + '</td></tr>';
 }
 tabla1 += '</tbody>';
 tabla1 += '</table>';
 return tabla1;
}
function calcularCuotas() {
 var plazo1 = document.getElementById('plazo').value;
 var plazo = parseInt(plazo1);
 var unidad = $('input[type=radio][name=inlineRadioOptions]:checked').val();
 var fpg = document.getElementById('formapago');
 var formapago = fpg.options[fpg.selectedIndex].text;
 if (formapago == 'Semanal') {
  var dp = document.getElementById('diapago');
  var diapago = dp.options[dp.selectedIndex].text;
 } else if (formapago == 'Quincenal') {
  diapago = 0;
 } else {
  var diapago = document.getElementById('diapago').value;
 }
 var fp1 = document.getElementById('fechaPrimeraCuota').value;
 var fp = String(fp1);
 var diap = fp.slice(8, 10);
 var mesp = fp.slice(5, 7) - 1;
 var aniop = fp.slice(0, 4);
 var dia = parseInt(diap);
 var mes = parseInt(mesp);
 var anio = parseInt(aniop);
 var fecha_primera_cuota = new Date(anio, mes, dia);
 if (unidad == 1) {
  mes = mes + plazo;
  var fecha_ultimo_dia = new Date(anio, mes, dia);
 } else {
  anio = anio + plazo;
  var fecha_ultimo_dia = new Date(anio, mes, dia);
 }

 var cuotas;
 switch (formapago) {
  case 'Semanal':
   var dias_totales;

   dias_totales = (fecha_ultimo_dia.getTime() - fecha_primera_cuota.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
   cuotas = dias_totales / 7;
   break;

  case 'Quincenal':
   dias_totales = (fecha_ultimo_dia.getTime() - fecha_primera_cuota.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
   cuotas = dias_totales / 15;
   break;

  case 'Mensual':
   if (unidad == 1) {
    cuotas = plazo;
   } else {
    cuotas = plazo * 12;
   }
   break;

  case 'Bimestral':
   if (unidad == 1) {
    cuotas = plazo / 2;
   } else {
    cuotas = plazo * 6;
   }
   break;
  case 'Trimestral':
   if (unidad == 1) {
    cuotas = plazo / 3;
   } else {
    cuotas = plazo * 4;
   }
   break;
 }
 cuotas = Math.ceil(cuotas);
 document.ready = document.getElementById('cuotas').value = cuotas;
 document.ready = document.getElementById('tasadiaria').value = calcularTasaDiaria();
}
function calcularTasaDiaria() {
 var tasa = document.getElementById('tasaanual').value;
 var tasaanual = parseInt(tasa);
 var tasa_diaria = tasaanual / 360;
 return tasa_diaria;
}

function calcular() {
 var cuotas = document.getElementById('cuotas').value;
 var fpg = document.getElementById('formapago');
 var formapago = fpg.options[fpg.selectedIndex].text;
 if (formapago == 'Semanal') {
  var dp = document.getElementById('diapago');
  var diapago = dp.options[dp.selectedIndex].text;
 } else if (formapago == 'Quincenal') {
  diapago = 0;
 } else {
  var diapago = document.getElementById('diapago').value;
 }
 var fd = document.getElementById('fechaDesembolso').value;
 var diad = fd.slice(8, 10);
 var mesd = fd.slice(5, 7) - 1;
 var aniod = fd.slice(0, 4);
 var dia = parseInt(diad);
 var mes = parseInt(mesd);
 var anio = parseInt(aniod);
 var fecha_desembolso = new Date(anio, mes, dia);

 var fp1 = document.getElementById('fechaPrimeraCuota').value;
 var fp = String(fp1);
 var diap = fp.slice(8, 10);
 var mesp = fp.slice(5, 7) - 1;
 var aniop = fp.slice(0, 4);
 var dia = parseInt(diap);
 var mes = parseInt(mesp);
 var anio = parseInt(aniop);
 var fecha_primera_cuota = new Date(anio, mes, dia);

 var f_d = fecha_desembolso;
 var fechac = new Date();
 const dias_semana = [ 'Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado' ];
 const meses = [
  'Enero',
  'Febrero',
  'Marzo',
  'Abril',
  'Mayo',
  'Junio',
  'Julio',
  'Agosto',
  'Septiembre',
  'Octubre',
  'Noviembre',
  'Diciembre'
 ];

 var fechas_cuotas = [];
 fechas_cuotas.push(fecha_primera_cuota);
 var i = 0;

 switch (formapago) {
  case 'Semanal':
   // este codigo funciona solo si el dia de  desembolso es el mismo dia que eligen para pagar

   if (diapago == dias_semana[fecha_primera_cuota.getDay()]) {
    while (i < cuotas) {
     dia = dia + 7;
     fechac = new Date(anio, mes, dia);
     fechas_cuotas.push(fechac);
     i++;
    }
   } else {
    while (diapago != dias_semana[fecha_primera_cuota.getDay()]) {
     dia = dia + 1;
     fecha_primera_cuota = new Date(anio, mes, dia);
    }

    while (i < cuotas) {
     fechac = new Date(anio, mes, dia);
     dia = dia + 7;
     fechas_cuotas.push(fechac);
     i++;
    }
   }
   break;

  case 'Quincenal':
   while (i < cuotas) {
    dia = dia + 15;
    fechac = new Date(anio, mes, dia);
    fechas_cuotas.push(fechac);
    i++;
   }
   break;

  case 'Mensual':
   var diac;
   diac = diapago;
   while (i < cuotas) {
    mes = mes + 1;
    fechac = new Date(anio, mes, diac);
    fechas_cuotas.push(fechac);

    i++;
   }
   break;

  case 'Bimestral':
   var diac;
   diac = diapago;
   while (i < cuotas) {
    mes = mes + 2;
    fechac = new Date(anio, mes, diac);
    fechas_cuotas.push(fechac);

    i++;
   }
   break;

  case 'Trimestral':
   var diac;
   diac = diapago;
   while (i < cuotas) {
    mes = mes + 3;
    fechac = new Date(anio, mes, diac);
    fechas_cuotas.push(fechac);

    i++;
   }
   break;
 }
 var vector_por_cuota = [];
 var fechas_de_cuota = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < fechas_cuotas.length; i++) {
  var dateCuota = fechas_cuotas[i].getDay();
  var nombrediaCuota = dias_semana[dateCuota];
  var diaCuota = fechas_cuotas[i].getDate();
  var mesCuota = fechas_cuotas[i].getMonth();
  var nombremesCuota = meses[mesCuota];
  var index = mes_especial.indexOf(nombremesCuota);
  if (index == -1) {
   vector_por_cuota[i] = 1;
  } else {
   vector_por_cuota[i] = vector_mensual[index];
  }
  var anioCuota = fechas_cuotas[i].getFullYear();

  fechas_de_cuota[i] = nombrediaCuota + ' ' + diaCuota + ' de ' + nombremesCuota + ' del ' + anioCuota;
 }

 var dias_diferencia = [];
 var dias_diferencia_acumulado = [];
 var x = 1;
 dias_diferencia[0] = (fechas_cuotas[0].getTime() - f_d.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
 dias_diferencia_acumulado[0] = dias_diferencia[0];
 while (x < cuotas) {
  dias_diferencia[x] = (fechas_cuotas[x].getTime() - fechas_cuotas[x - 1].getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  dias_diferencia_acumulado[x] = dias_diferencia_acumulado[x - 1] + dias_diferencia[x];
  x++;
 }

 document.querySelector('#resultado').innerHTML = generarTabla(
  cuotas,
  fechas_de_cuota,
  dias_diferencia,
  dias_diferencia_acumulado,
  vector_por_cuota
 );
}

function generarTabla(cuotas, fechas_de_cuota, dias_diferencia, dias_diferencia_acumulado, vector_por_cuota) {
 var tabla =
  "<table id='tablita' class='table' style:'margin: 0 auto;'> <thead class='thead-light'> <tr><th scope='col'>Cuota</th><th scope='col'>Fecha de Cuota</th><th scope='col'>Dias de diferencia</th><th scope='col'>Dias de diferencia acumulado</th><th scope='col'>Vector Mensual</th></tr></thead>";
 tabla += '<tbody>';
 var a = 1;
 for (var i = 0; i < cuotas; i++) {
  tabla +=
   '<tr><td>' +
   a +
   '</td><td>' +
   fechas_de_cuota[i] +
   '</td><td>' +
   dias_diferencia[i] +
   '</td><td>' +
   dias_diferencia_acumulado[i] +
   '</td><td>' +
   vector_por_cuota[i] +
   '</td></tr>';
  a++;
 }
 tabla += '</tbody>';
 tabla += '</table>';
 return tabla;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Fechas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.11/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.11/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1 class="display-1 text-center bg-light text-dark">Cuotas</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1"></div>
                <div class="col-10">
                      
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="plazo">Plazo</label>
                            
                              <input class="form-control" type="number" name="plazo" id="plazo" placeholder="Introduce el plazo" min="1" max="20" step="1" required>
                              <label for="unidad" id="unidad">Unidad: </label>
                              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="1" checked> Meses
                                </label>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="2"> Años
                                </label>
                          </div>              
                        </div>
                        
                       
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="formapago">Forma de Pago</label>
                                <select name="formapago" id="formapago" class="form-control" onchange="cargardiaDepago(this.value);" required>
                                    <option value="0">Elige una opcion</option>
                                    <option value='1'>Semanal</option>
                                    <option value='2'>Quincenal</option>
                                    <option value='3'>Mensual</option>
                                    <option value='4'>Bimestral</option>
                                    <option value="5">Trimestral</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="input_dia_pago">
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="tasaanual">Tasa anual%</label>
                          <input type="number" name="tasaanual" id="tasaanual" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="fechaDesembolso">Fecha de desembolso</label>
                            <input type="date" name="fechaDesembolso" id="fechaDesembolso" class="form-control" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="fechaPrimeraCuota">Fecha de 1° cuota</label>
                            <input type="date" name="fechaPrimeraCuota" id="fechaPrimeraCuota" class="form-control" required>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                          <label for="mesEspecial">Meses especiales</label>
                          <select name="mesEspecial" id="mesEspecial" class="form-control">
                          <option value="13">Elige un mes</option>
                          <option value='0'>Enero</option>
                          <option value='1'>Febrero</option>
                          <option value='2'>Marzo</option>
                          <option value='3'>Abril</option>
                          <option value="4">Mayo</option>
                          <option value="5">Junio</option>
                          <option value="6">Julio</option>
                          <option value="7">Agosto</option>
                          <option value="8">Septiembre</option>
                          <option value="9">Octubre</option>
                          <option value="10">Noviembre</option>
                          <option value="11">Diciembre</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="vectorMensual">Vector del mes</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="vectorMensual" id="vectorMensual" placeholder="Introduce el vector" value="1" min="0" max="10" step="0.25" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
                            <label for="guardar"> </label>
                            <br>
                            <button name="guardar" class="btn btn-light" id="guardar" onclick="guardar_mes_especial()">Guardar</button>
                          </div>
                         
                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group text-center">
                          <div id="mesespecial"></div>
                       </div>
                        
                        <div>

                          <div class="container">
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                  <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                      <button name="calcularcuotas"  class="btn btn-primary"
                                          id="calcularcuotas" onclick="calcularCuotas()">Calcular Cuotas</button></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="cuotas">Cantidad de cuotas</label>
                          <input readonly type="text" name="cuotas" class="form-control" id="cuotas" placeholder="Cuotas" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tasadiaria">Tasa Diaria</label>
                        <input readonly type="text" name="tasadiaria" class="form-control" id="tasadiaria" placeholder="Tasa Diaria" required>
                    </div>
                      <div>

                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                    <button name="enviar"  class="btn btn-primary"
                                        id="enviar" onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div id="resultado"></div>
                         </div>
                   
                
                
                
              </div>

        </div>
    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muy Buenas! Se puede hacer perfectamente lo que quieres, lo único que tienes que hacer es meter la tabla dentro de un `<div>` por ejemplo y a ese le tienes que dar un tamaño fijo. Algo así:

```css
td {
    border: 1px royalblue dotted;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#taula {
    height: 200px !important;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div id="taula">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>32</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>34</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Si nos referimos a tu código, y concretamente a la función de `js` que genera la tabla seria algo así:

```js
function generarTabla(cuotas, fechas_de_cuota, dias_diferencia, dias_diferencia_acumulado, vector_por_cuota) {
    var tamanoFijo = document.createElement("div");
    tamanoFijo.style.height = "300px"; //Aqui realmente podrias poner el tamaño que tu desees
    tamanoFijo.style.overflow = "auto";
    var tabla =
        "<table id='tablita' class='table' style:'margin: 0 auto;'> <thead class='thead-light'> <tr><th scope='col'>Cuota</th><th scope='col'>Fecha de Cuota</th><th scope='col'>Dias de diferencia</th><th scope='col'>Dias de diferencia acumulado</th><th scope='col'>Vector Mensual</th></tr></thead>";
    tabla += '<tbody>';
    var a = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < cuotas; i++) {
        tabla +=
            '<tr><td>' +
            a +
            '</td><td>' +
            fechas_de_cuota[i] +
            '</td><td>' +
            dias_diferencia[i] +
            '</td><td>' +
            dias_diferencia_acumulado[i] +
            '</td><td>' +
            vector_por_cuota[i] +
            '</td></tr>';
        a++;
    }
    tabla += '</tbody>';
    tabla += '</table></div>';
    tamanoFijo.innerHTML = tabla;
    return tamanoFijo;
}
```

IMPORTANTE: Ten en cuenta que aquí te hago un `return` de un objeto y no de código directamente así que para que te lo imprima bien utiliza `appendChild();`:
Por ejemplo digamos que quieres imprimir tu tabla en el body:
`document.body.appendchild(generarTabla(..., ..., ..., ..., ...))`

Si no te gusta, siempre puedes modificar la funión para que te haga un `return` de código directamente. `var tabla = "<div style='height:200px;overflow:auto'><table id='tablita'...`

Espero que te sirva mi respuesta.

Comment: Me sirvio mucho, solo use la parte del archivo css, y le deje el alto de un tamaño fijo y el ancho en auto. Además me sirvio para poder alinear el texto, ya que me habia olvidado como se hacia, pero como se puede alinear en forma vertical?

Comment: Si que existen varias maneras con css. Podrían ser: `vertical-align: middle;` o `transform: translateY(-50%);`